# it possible to select two elements from one array and showing as one string

Tags: python, split, strip

Is that possible select two elements from **one** array. In my case I want to **select** like this `a[1,2]` and show only `'12'` in one string format.
Instant of `a[0]`+`a[1]`, any other possible way to do it quick ?

**python code**

```
 a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
 a[0]
```

**execution result**

```
 '1'
```

**expected code like**

```
 a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
 a[0,1]
```

**expected result** (one string)

```
  '12'
```

Comment: ```a[0]+a[1]```. No you cannot do ```a[0,1]```. You are passing a tuple instead of a single integer

Comment: dear, thanks a lot, any other possible way ?

Comment: ```''.join(a[0:2])```

Comment: dear, thanks a lot !

Comment: Most welcome. Happy to know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an arbitrary list of indexes you can select those with a comprehension and `join()`:

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']

indexes = [1, 3, 4]
''.join(a[n] for n in indexes)
# 245
```

Alternatively you can use the builtin `itemgetter`. This is handy if you want to get the same items from multiple lists:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
b = ['5','6','7','8','9']

gettr = itemgetter(1,3, 4)

"".join(gettr(a))
# 245

"".join(gettr(b))
# 689
```

Answer (score 2):

Python can concatenate the indices into one string so to get your desired output you can do:

```py
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
print(a[0]+a[1])
```

which returns:

```
'12'
```

Comment: It returns a string 12: ```'12'```.

Answer (score 2):

You could custom a new class to achieve that:

```
class List_:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        return "".join(self.data[i] for i in pos)
    
a = List_(['1','2','3','4','5'])
a[0, 1]
```

And the result:

```
'12'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try slicing the array to isolate the section you want, then just string `join` to form a single string.  For example, for the first 3 elements you may try:

```py
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
print(''.join(a[0:3]))  # prints '123'
```

Comment: @Mary Happy to assist you, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments says, you can use `print(a[0]+a[1])` or `print("".join(a[0:2]))` to get your desired output.